# Drawing Piecewise Functions

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the following piecewise function in MATLAB:

```
x=linspace(0,1,100);
e=1;
n=9;
N(e,:) = (n*x-e+1).*(x>(e-1)/n).*(x<e/n) + (-n*x+e+1).*(x>e/n).*(x<(e+1)/n);
plot(x,N(e,:));
```

And the result is this:

[image: graph]

instead of an isosceles triangle as it should be. Does anybody know how to fix this or have any alternative?

Comment: The given code doesn't compile. Please, provide a working piece of code.

Comment: Done. It's taken from a larger block of code, so I apologize for the inconvenience using the 'e' and 'n' variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your function to actually have value of 1 at `x=0.11` instead of value of 0. For this, you can simply replace `(x<e/n)` with `(x<=e/n)`.